# IBM App center not working for iOS8

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

IBM App center is not working for iOS 8 with Worklight version 6.1.0.2

Is there any way or workaround to get app center working for iOS 8 without upgrading IBM Worklight to 6.2 please suggest.

Thanks
djrecker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for iOS 8 was added some months ago to all Worklight 6.x releases, including for Application Center. The reason why Application Center is not working for you may be due to Dojo incompatibility with iOS 8, which has been resolved.

You need to upgrade your Worklight installation to the latest iFix. You can obtain that from the IBM Fix Central website.
See the following tech note for further insturctions: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21684538

If this does not resolve your issue then provide more concrete details, like: what is not working and any errors you may saw, logs, etc.

Comment: For the steps on "Upgrading the Dojo Toolkit" can it simply replaced by installing the latest fixed IBM Worklight Studio (6.0 in my case) ?