# IBM App center app doesn't work on Android 5.0.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

We are facing an issue with IBM app centre app where it is not working on Android 5.0.1.

The issue is once we login to the IBM app through android device (Samsung S5 with OS 5.0.1) All our applications are not clickable and they just got highlighted and we can't go to the install page for our specific app.

It works on pervious versions of Android OS.

Worklight Server version: 6.2.0.01.20141013-1735.

I'm not sure if this is the same issue that we faced earlier with iOS8 and we have to get an ifix for it.

Reference : [IBM App center not working for iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059451/ibm-app-center-not-working-for-ios8)

Thanks.

Comment: First download the latest iFix for 6.2 and then try again with the latest sources of the App Center installer application. If it is failing still, also provide LogCat logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using a very old iFix of Worklight 6.2, my first and foremost suggestion for you is to download the latest available 6.2 iFix from IBM Fix Central, and use the AppCenter client sources from that iFix.

See if the problem repeats itself as well. If yes, you will need to open a PMR (support ticket).